# Getting string/text after a certain phrase

Tags: c#, indexof

I need to get the word after "Running module" from a log file. The word after "Running module" always ends with a full stop (.)
I need to insert this word in a array for later access when I need it.

Example text from log is:

> 25.5.2018 10:42:35.621 Status message 0884:Running module SamplesSim.
>
> 25.5.2018 10:42:35.621 Status message 0120:Data Input: Opening:  T:\RCS\BiggieStatementsOn\PRINT\INPUTJACK\FCA_HomeBandAccounts_23052018.csv. (DataInput1)

I've tried using the `indexOf()`, but I keep getting "Run" as my output.

Here is my code:

```
string consoleOutput = compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

startIndex = consoleOutput.IndexOf("Running module");
string[] ModuleParams;
string runningMod = "";

if (startIndex != -1)
{
    lastIndex = startIndex +3;
    if (lastIndex != -1)
    {
        ModuleParams = consoleOutput
                           .Substring(startIndex, lastIndex - startIndex)
                           .Split(' ');

        runningMod = ModuleParams[0];
                     //.Substring(4).Replace("Running module", "").Trim();
    }                                
    Console.WriteLine(runningMod);
}
```

Comment: your code is always doing a substring of length 3. ModuleParams[0] will always be "Run".

Answer (score 2):

I corrected your code, now it outputs `SamplesSim`

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            string consoleOutput = @"
                25.5.2018 10:42:35.621 Status message 0884:Running module SamplesSim.

                25.5.2018 10:42:35.621 Status message 0120:Data Input: Opening: T:\RCS\BiggieStatementsOn\PRINT\INPUTJACK\FCA_HomeBandAccounts_23052018.csv. (DataInput1)
            ";
            string wordToFind = "Running module";
            var startIndex = consoleOutput.IndexOf(wordToFind);
            string[] ModuleParams;
            string runningMod = "";

            if (startIndex != -1)
            {
                var lastIndex = startIndex + wordToFind.Length;
                if (lastIndex != -1)
                {
                    ModuleParams = consoleOutput
                                       .Substring(startIndex+wordToFind.Length, consoleOutput.Length - (startIndex+wordToFind.Length))
                        .Split(new char[]{' ','\n','.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                    runningMod = ModuleParams[0];
                                 //.Substring(4).Replace("Running module", "").Trim();
                }                                
                Console.WriteLine(runningMod);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: my string won't always be "25.5.2018 10:42:35.621 Status message 0884:Running module SamplesSim." The last word and dates can change.

Comment: this is just pseudo code, change it according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

There may be cleaner ways to do it, but this should work.

```
string text = consoleOutput.Split(new string[] { "Running module" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('.')[0];
```

So I split the console output by the string "Running module" and took the text on the right side of the split. I then split again by '.' and took the value on the left side. This is pretty messy, so I'll be looking out for improvements.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, you may have to trim spaces from the start of the string as if you have something like "Running module renamer" your output after splitting will be " renamer". You can just use `text = text.Trim();` to remove all the white spaces, or `text = text.TrimStart();` to remove white spaces from just the start. Alternatively, you can add it on the end of the code above, but I've heard it's bad practice.

```
string text = consoleOutput.Split(new string[] { "Running module" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split('.')[0].Trim();
```

It might be better to spread it out a bit

```
string text = consoleOutput.Split(new string[] { "Running module" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
text = text.Split('.')[0];
text = text.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
string mystring = "25.5.2018 10:42:35.621 Status message 0884:Running module SamplesSim.";
string keyWord = "Running module";
string extractedWord = mystring.Substring(mystring.IndexOf(keyWord) + keyWord.Length).Trim();
Console.WriteLine(extractedWord);
```

The above code will return `SampleSim` It also removes any whitespaces in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression as such. See https://regex101.com/r/Xm25z5/1

```
/Running module\s[a-zA-Z]+.$/gm
```

Comment: If the intention is to have `.` match a literal period character then you have to escape it. A `.` in a regular expressions matches any single character expect a newline.